# vue-router: nested named views problem. Additional component is not visible

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I found this example in vue-router documentation:

https://jsfiddle.net/posva/22wgksa3/?fbclid=IwAR2WITnr6cmA_3rUgOCCvPrHASKfSW9QsvEKv4HrxBmuDUN1VmWSWufCtAI

```
const router = new VueRouter({
   mode: 'history',
   routes: [{ 
       path: '/settings',
       // You could also have named views at tho top
       component: UserSettings,
       children: [{
           path: 'emails',
           component: UserEmailsSubscriptions
           }, {
           path: 'profile',
           components: {
               default: UserProfile,
               helper: UserProfilePreview
           }
       }]
   }]
})
```

I tried to do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/pt9o6h8e/

```
const router = new VueRouter({
   mode: 'history',
   routes: [{ 
       path: '/settings',
       components: {
           default: UserSettings,
           test: TestComponent
       }
       children: [{
           path: 'emails',
           component: UserEmailsSubscriptions
           }, {
           path: 'profile',
           components: {
               default: UserProfile,
               helper: UserProfilePreview
           }
       }]
   }]
})
```

but TestComponent is not visible. 
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specified your route like this,

```
{ 
  path: '/settings',
  // You could also have named views at tho top
  components: {
    default: UserSettings,
    test: TestComponent
  }
}
```

`UserSettings` and `TestComponent` are considered sibling components so when rendering, it will look for a named `router-view` next to the default `router-view` that you specified on your top-most div which is `#app`.

> However, you put `<router-view name="test" />` **inside** `UserSettings`
>   template so it didn't find the `router-view` to render `TestComponent`
>   to.

To fix this, either move the `test` router-view from `UserSettings` to the `#app`.

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Nested Named Views</h1>
  <router-view></router-view>
  <router-view name="test" class="us__content us__content--helper"/>
</div>
```

Or, if you want to keep it inside `UserSettings`, change how you declared it by moving `test: TestComponent` inside either of your children routes.

See [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/analizapandac/umxejdpy/1/).